# Android download list of files with callback

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've got an Activity from which i need to download and save list of files. Files and names are stored in `Map <String,String>`. After downloading all files I need to call function in my Activity.

I've already have AsyncTask class which downloads and saves files and an interface which callbacks to Activity. 
How can i pass `Map<String,String>` to Asynctask or maybe there is another solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Add a constructor to your async class with a Map as a parameter.

Comment: @bbaker I thought about it, but later in this activity i also need to download file using only file url, and in this case i would need two create another async class which will load file from url. and i will get two classes which are doing similar tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that is suitable for an AsyncTask. You should look into implementing a custom Service, probably an IntentService.

There's a very good tutorial at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: I can provide an example. I have a mapview activity in which I have list of markers and list of marker images, first  I need to download this images and then render markers with images on map.

Comment: Thanks. That was really what i've been searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Android [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) and a list of IDs

```java
DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/myfile.mp3");

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setTitle("My File");
request.setDescription("Downloading");
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + folderName + "/myfile.mp3"));

mList_refid.add(downloadmanager.enqueue(request));
```

To setup a callback, use `registerReceiver`

```java
mList_refid = new ArrayList<>();
mDownloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
            if (mList_refid != null && mList_refid.contains(downloadId)) {
                mList_refid.remove(downloadId); // File is downloaded, remove it from ID list.
            }
        } else
            Log.e(LOG, "BroadcastReceiver on receive action not handled : " + action);
    }
};
registerReceiver(mDownloadReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```